# Dragging and dropping a <li> id to a text input

Tags: jquery, html-lists, drag

I've searched the interwebs, and I'm not working out how to do that. I would like to have something like a file list, and the drag and drop a file (a `<li>` element) and write it's id to a text field. Would it be possible ?

Comment: You can use `Jquery Ui` draggable and droppable

Comment: Yes. It would be possible. Your own attempt?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible using jQuery UI draggable and droppable plugins. You need to include jQuery UI script reference into your page.

jQuery UI CDN - http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js

Html

```
<ul>
    <li id="li1">Li 1</li>
    <li id="li2">Li 2</li>
    <li id="li3">Li 3</li>
</ul>
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
```

JS

```
$('ul li').draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: 'clone'
});

$("#textbox").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        this.value = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
    }
});
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/bxjmtdkv/2/