# Allow dragstart-Event without loosing focus of other controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I want to implement some draggable elements on the page, which should not break the currently focused control on the page. That is what I tried:

```js
$('input').focus();
$('div').on('mousedown', function(event) {
  // event.preventDefault(); // drag does not work anymore
  // $('input').focus(); // focus still lost
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div draggable="true">Hello World</div><br />
The input field should not loose focus, when dragging "Hello World".<br />
<input type="text" />
```

If I activate event.preventDefault(), the focus is not lost on mousedown, but the drag operation cannot start anymore. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you reset the focus using mouseup?

Comment: In this answer to this question it works with using jQuery UI. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669577/dragging-and-dropping-a-li-id-to-a-text-input

Comment: @Colin jQueryUI does not use HTML5 draggable-Attribute in this demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, `setTimeout` will solve your problem

```js
$('input').focus();
$('div').on('mousedown', function(event) {
  window.setTimeout(
    function() {
      $('input').focus();
    }, 1);
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div draggable="true">Hello World</div><br />
The input field should not loose focus, when dragging "Hello World".<br />
<input type="text" />
```

**Result;**
[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbmmejyz/2/)

Hope helps,

Comment: Hmm, that seems a little better. Technically the focus is lost for 1 ms. There is a little flickering in chrome on windows. The textcursor is not blinking anymore after releasing the drag operation anywhere. But it may be a solution.

Comment: you can put it in a snippet, why gif?

Comment: Use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout` and flicker no more! :-)

Comment: @PeterMiller You sir just saved a lot of time for me :D

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").on("mousedown",function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$("div").draggable();
$("input").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                $("input").css('background', 'rgb(0,200,0)');
                }
            });
});

});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   

<div draggable="true">Hello World</div><br />
The input field should not loose focus, when dragging "Hello World".<br />
<input type="text" />
```